# AWS CodeDeploy [FATAL] Unable to get this instance's ID; cannot continue

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

We're trying to run an AWS CodeDeploy with ELB Classic and an Auto Scaling Group. We are using the aws Github example scripts: deregister_from_elb.sh and register_with_elb.sh, as described in the [[]](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-codedeploy-samples/tree/master/load-balancing/elb-%20v2), but CodeDeploy returns the following error:

> LifecycleEvent - ApplicationStop Script - \ DeployHelper \
>   deregister_from_elb.bat [stderr]
>   /cygdrive/c/ProgramData\Amazon\CodeDeploy\dbfa703d-7f11-4b76-9600-789231415d43\d-U1DS4LVHN\deployment-archive\DeployHelper/common_functions.sh:
>   line 112: curl: command not found [stderr]
>   /cygdrive/c/ProgramData\Amazon\CodeDeploy\dbfa703d-7f11-4b76-9600-789231415d43\d-U1DS4LVHN\deployment-archive\DeployHelper/common_functions.sh:
>   line 112: curl: command not found [stderr] Running AWS CLI with
>   region: [stderr]
>   /cygdrive/c/ProgramData\Amazon\CodeDeploy\dbfa703d-7f11-4b76-9600-789231415d43\d-U1DS4LVHN\deployment-archive\DeployHelper/common_functions.sh:
>   line 723: curl: command not found [stderr] [FATAL] Unable to get this
>   instance's ID; can not continue.

[image: CodeDeploy]
[image: Error message]
Guesses about what may be occurring?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 curl: command not found
```

Install `curl` if not installed and use the absolute path of `curl` and try again.

> [stderr]
>   /cygdrive/c/ProgramData\Amazon\CodeDeploy\dbfa703d-7f11-4b76-9600-789231415d43\d-U1DS4LVHN\deployment-archive\DeployHelper/common_functions.sh:
>   line 112: **curl: command not found** [stderr]
>
> [stderr]
>   /cygdrive/c/ProgramData\Amazon\CodeDeploy\dbfa703d-7f11-4b76-9600-789231415d43\d-U1DS4LVHN\deployment-archive\DeployHelper/common_functions.sh:
>   line 723: **curl: command not found** [stderr]

Comment: Work! Thank you @helloV